# How can I use if Statment on ImageView, When ImageView is not updated

Tags: android, xml

I have an image view with src from drawable, and I want to use if statement, when the user doesn't change the profile eating button view, can't continue

I tried to use this, .getDrawable()==ResourcesCompat.getDrawable` but didn't work

**xml**

```
   <ImageView            
            android:id="@+id/imgProfil"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/RGroupWaktu"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-103dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-103dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/RGroupWaktu"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/RGroupWaktu"
            android:onClick="onUploadImageClick"
            android:src="@drawable/iconrounded"
            app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
```

**Java**
`if (mProfil.getDrawable()==ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.iconrounded, null)`

I want when the user does not replace the image on the ImageView then the User cannot continue to the next stage

Comment: you can use `settag` on image view when user set new image on it . use `if` for `gettag` and compare it to `null`

Comment: can you give an example, because I've tried set tags and it didn't work

Comment: Can you add your complete java code where you use this imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set/replace the Image on the imageview then set a tag name also :

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.iconrounded);
imageview.setTag("iconrounded");
```

Then get the tag name and check it :

```
String imagename =  (String)imageview.getTag();

if(imagename!=null && imagename.equals("iconrounded")){

   //go to next Activity 

}else {

    // Show a  alert  toast  for change 

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I use this and my compilation runs it, replaces or doesn't replace the image in the imageview the user can still continue

Comment: Sekarang saya berhasil, dengan menambahkan "else if" terimakasih @Noor Hossain

Comment: I have tested  just now,  and it's working, like a  charm. After Replacing the correct Image you have to set  tag immediately at the next line @projecttrinof.